# Good software for dynamical analysis of a system of ODEs 

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Hi all

I want to analyze a system of ~200 ODE (non-linear) and want to calculate the stable points. Can you suggest a good software for the analysis. I am comfortable with MATLAB and C++.

I researched and found good things about MATCONT and XPPAUT. Are they the state-of-art in the field?

Thanks
Ayesha

Answer (score 2):

Some software packages at Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Software_for_ODE_solving)

At CASC (Center for Applied Scientific Computing) there is ODEPACK (Serial FORTRAN solvers for Ordinary Differential Equation initial value problems) [here](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/software.html) and BABEL:

"Babel provides high-performance language interoperability and middleware for scientific applications. It also provides coarse-grained distributed computing using remote method invocation. Babel currently supports C, C++, Java, Python, and various dialects of Fortran."

Also, you can try SUNDIALS (SUite of Nonlinear and DIfferential/ALgebraic equation Solvers) available [here](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html).

SUNDIALS provides a **Matlab** interface to CVODES (solves IVP for ODE systems), IDA (solves IVP dor DAE systems) and KINSOL (solves nonlinear algebraic problems).